# Customized Merge Request Detail Page

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm actually searching for an option to customize the Details Page of a Merge Request.

I would like to have two additional pieces of information on this page.

The first one would be some kind of a Dry Merge with some more information than the default one is able to give me.

And the Second one would be a test whether the branch has common roots with the master or not.

For both points I have built git aliases which give me the necessary information.

Dry Merge:

```
git config --global alias.mergetest '!f() { git merge --no-commit --no-ff "$1"; git merge --abort; echo "Merge aborted"; }
```

Common roots:

```
git config --global alias.frommaster 'merge-base --fork-point master'
```

But now I can't find any way to implement this additional information into the Merge Request Detail Page of GitLab - is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I think you can achieve this is by using webhooks and the GitLab API.

1. Create a Web Hook which fires whenever a [Merge Request event](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/web_hooks/web_hooks.html#merge-request-events) happens.
2. This Webhook will make an [API call](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/merge_requests.html#update-mr) to update the Merge Request with the output of your two commands.